# Creating uniform random quaternion and multiplication of two quaternions

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, quaternions

I have a python (NumPy) function which creates a uniform random quaternion. I would like to get two quaternion multiplication as 2-dimensional returned array from the same or an another function. The formula of quaternion multiplication in my recent case is Q1*Q2 and Q2*Q1. Here, `Q1=(w0, x0, y0, z0)` and `Q2=(w1, x1, y1, z1)` are two quaternions. The expected two quaternion multiplication output (as 2-d returned array) should be

```
return([-x1*x0 - y1*y0 - z1*z0 + w1*w0, x1*w0 + y1*z0 - z1*y0 +
    w1*x0, -x1*z0 + y1*w0 + z1*x0 + w1*y0, x1*y0 - y1*x0 + z1*w0 +
    w1*z0])
```

Can anyone help me please? My codes are here:

```
def randQ(N):
    #Generates a uniform random quaternion
    #James J. Kuffner 2004 
    #A random array 3xN
    s = random.rand(3,N)
    sigma1 = sqrt(1.0 - s[0])
    sigma2 = sqrt(s[0])
    theta1 = 2*pi*s[1]
    theta2 = 2*pi*s[2]
    w = cos(theta2)*sigma2
    x = sin(theta1)*sigma1
    y = cos(theta1)*sigma1
    z = sin(theta2)*sigma2
    return array([w, x, y, z])
```

Comment: What's the question or problem?

Comment: @hpaulj My question is how I can get Q1*Q2 and Q2*Q1 as returned array from another function. Please look at my expected Q1*Q2 returned array format (just before the function). I would like to make Q2*Q1 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple rendition of your request would be:

```
In [70]: def multQ(Q1,Q2):
    ...:     w0,x0,y0,z0 = Q1   # unpack
    ...:     w1,x1,y1,z1 = Q2
    ...:     return([-x1*x0 - y1*y0 - z1*z0 + w1*w0, x1*w0 + y1*z0 - z1*y0 +
    ...:     w1*x0, -x1*z0 + y1*w0 + z1*x0 + w1*y0, x1*y0 - y1*x0 + z1*w0 +
    ...:     w1*z0])
    ...:     

In [72]: multQ(randQ(1),randQ(2))
Out[72]: 
[array([-0.37695449,  0.79178506]),
 array([-0.38447116,  0.22030199]),
 array([ 0.44019022,  0.56496059]),
 array([ 0.71855397,  0.07323243])]
```

The result is a list of 4 arrays.  Just wrap it in `np.array()` to get a 2d array:

```
In [73]: M=np.array(_)

In [74]: M
Out[74]: 
array([[-0.37695449,  0.79178506],
       [-0.38447116,  0.22030199],
       [ 0.44019022,  0.56496059],
       [ 0.71855397,  0.07323243]])
```

I haven't tried to understand or clean up your description - just rendering it as working code.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old but as I found it interesting, for future reference I herewith write an answer: if no special data type for quaternions is desirable, then a quaternion can be written as a tuple of a real number and a normal vector as an array of floats. Thus, mathematically, based on the process mentioned [here](https://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/hamiltons-quaternions-and-3d-rotation-with-python/), the Hamilton product of two quaternions $\hat{q}_1=(w_1,\mathbf{v}_1k$ and $\hat{q}_2=(w_2,\mathbf{v}_2)$ would be:
$$\hat{q}_1 \hat{q}_2=(w_1 w_2-\mathbf{v}^T_1\mathbf{v}_2, w_1 \mathbf{v}_2+w_2 \mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_1\times \mathbf{v}_2)$$[image]

Sorry for the [math notation that cannot be rendered in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309307/latex-on-stack-overflow-any-way-to-include-a-formula).
Thus in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
q1=(w1,v1)
q2=(w2,v2)
q1q2=(w1*w2-np.matmul(v1.T,v2),w1*v2+w2*v1+np.cross(v1,v2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2-Dimensional Array is an array like this: foo[0][1]

You don't need to do that.  Multiplying two quaternions yields one single quaternion. I don't see why you would need a two-dimensional array, or how you would even use one.

Just have a function that takes two arrays as arguments:

```
def multQuat(q1, q2):
```

then return the relevant array.

```
return array([-q2[1] * q1[1], ...])
```

Comment: In `numpy` we index a 2d array with `foo[0,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is pretty old but would like to add a function using the *pyquaternion* library to calculate quaternion multiplication. The quaternion multiplication mentioned in the question is called the *Hamilton* product. You can use it like below...

```
from pyquaternion import Quaternion
q1 = Quaternion()
q2 = Quaternion()

q1_q2 = q1*q2
```

You can find more about this library here http://kieranwynn.github.io/pyquaternion/

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python module that adds a quaternion dtype to NumPy.
Please check out the documentation for the quaternion module [here](https://quaternion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Here is an example from the documentation. It looks native to the usage of NumPy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import quaternion
>>> np.quaternion(1,0,0,0)
quaternion(1, 0, 0, 0)
>>> q1 = np.quaternion(1,2,3,4)
>>> q2 = np.quaternion(5,6,7,8)
>>> q1 * q2
quaternion(-60, 12, 30, 24)
>>> a = np.array([q1, q2])
>>> a
array([quaternion(1, 2, 3, 4), quaternion(5, 6, 7, 8)], dtype=quaternion)
>>> np.exp(a)
array([quaternion(1.69392, -0.78956, -1.18434, -1.57912),
       quaternion(138.909, -25.6861, -29.9671, -34.2481)], dtype=quaternion)
```