# Rotating a point to be parallel to a direction vector delivers wrong vector. Why?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, rotation

I would need to rotate a vector defined by its start at (0,0,0) and ending on a given point in order to be parallel to a given direction vector. For this reason, I have based my code on the following answer:

> I guess by "parallel" you intend "pointing in the same direction."
>
> We may as well rotate (d,e,f)
> in the plane spanned by v=(d,e,f) and w=(a,b,c). The axis of rotation >would be around a vector perpendicular to this plane such as a=v×w, which >you'd normalize to a unit length vector u. Finally, we'd need the angle of >rotation θ, which can be retrieved from v⋅w=∥v∥∥w∥cos(θ) by solving for θ.
>
> Then following the scheme for using quaternions to perform rotations, the >quaternion you're looking for is q=cos(θ/2)+usin(θ/2). The transformation >x→qxq−1 moves v to point in the same direction as w.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734707/how-to-rotate-a-3d-vector-to-be-parallel-to-another-3d-vector-using-quaternions/735136#735136

I have managed to implement this, though by visualizing the results, it is clear that they are not parallel.

```py
## Example code

def get_unit_vector(vector):
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)

def get_angle_between_vectors(vector1, vector2):
    unit_vector_1 = get_unit_vector(vector1)
    unit_vector_2 = get_unit_vector(vector2)
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(unit_vector_2, unit_vector_1))
    return min(angle, np.pi-angle)

def rotate_point(point, direction):
    # get the axis and normalize it
    axis = np.cross(point, direction)
    norm_axis = get_unit_vector(axis)
    angle = get_angle_between_vectors(point, direction)
    q = np.cos((angle/2))+norm_axis*np.sin(angle/2)
    q = get_unit_vector(q)
    new_point = (q*point)*np.conj(q)
    new_angle = get_angle_between_vectors(new_point, direction)
    if new_angle != 0:
        q = np.cos((np.pi-angle / 2)) + norm_axis * np.sin(np.pi-angle / 2)
        new_point = (q * point) * (np.conj(q))
    return new_point
```

Here the results:

[image: visualization of the 3 vectors]

As stated, I would expect both orange and green vectors to be parallels but they are not. Are there steps that I am missing?

Comment: how can a point be "parallel" to anything? It can be on a line but thats about it ... around what are you rotating? do you want to put the point on the orange line? if so what then? do you need to do something else with the rotation you used to place the point onto your correct line?

Comment: The line `q = np.cos((angle/2))+norm_axis*np.sin(angle/2)` sounds fishy: it's adding a number to a 3-coordinate vector, which is a valid numpy operation but has no mathematical sense here. Not sure what the fix would be though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The definition wasn't clear enough. I meant a vector starting from (0,0,0) to the given point. The axis is the perpendicular vector to the plane, such as stated in the quoted answer. In other words, I am trying to align the two vectors, such that green takes the same direction as orange.

Comment: @Leporello I'm not really fit in vector rotation, but this follows the same as the definition provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternion_as_rotations)

Comment: So the "point" is a fixpoint and you have a vector goiung through 0,0,0 and your point and you want to rotate this vector around your fixpoint so it is ending up parallel to your other vector but no longer going through 0,0,0? The other vector which is your "template" also goes through 0,0,0?

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, the rotation should return a modification of the blue vector (defined by 0,0,0 and the fixed point) so that it goes to the same direction as the orange vector (direction vector). This does not mean that the "fixed point" will be crossed by the new vector (aka the green one).

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes the template vector also goes through 0,0,0 (it is a unit vector)

Comment: The comments under the linked answer clarify that `u` is a unit **quaternion** which represents the axis of rotation `A`, i.e. `u = [w=0, xyz=A]`. `cos(θ/2)` *also* represents a quaternion with real part equal to `cos(θ/2)`. Therefore the quaternion `q`  has components of `[w=cos(θ/2), xyz=A*sin(θ/2)]`, which is in agreement with other tutorials on the web. Conclusion: always refer to more than one source.

Comment: @MWP If you are trying to do quaternion arithmetic, then `new_point = (q*point)*np.conj(q)` does not do what you think it does. [Per the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.conj.html), np.conj returns the complex conjugate, element-wise (so it changes nothing here, since you have a vector of real values).

Comment: ...well actually, `q` is still a 3d vector where the cos part gets added three times. Basically, you did not define q as a quaternion in the code you give.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thx! Actually, with your comment, I understood the problem!

Comment: @Leporello I ended up using an own conjugate function, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some modification I managed to get the desired output. I got the multiplication function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000758/how-to-multiply-two-quaternions-by-python-or-numpy).

```py
def get_unit_vector(vector):
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)


def get_angle_between_vectors(vector1, vector2):
    unit_vector_1 = get_unit_vector(vector1)
    unit_vector_2 = get_unit_vector(vector2)
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(unit_vector_2, unit_vector_1))
    return min(angle, np.pi-angle)

def quaternion_conjugate(q):
    first = q[0]
    q_prime = -1*q
    q_prime[0] = first
    return q_prime

def quaternion_multiply(quaternion1, quaternion0):
    w0, x0, y0, z0 = quaternion0
    w1, x1, y1, z1 = quaternion1
    return np.array([-x1 * x0 - y1 * y0 - z1 * z0 + w1 * w0,
                     x1 * w0 + y1 * z0 - z1 * y0 + w1 * x0,
                     -x1 * z0 + y1 * w0 + z1 * x0 + w1 * y0,
                     x1 * y0 - y1 * x0 + z1 * w0 + w1 * z0], dtype=np.float64)


def rotate_point(point, direction):
    axis = np.cross(point, direction)
    norm_axis = get_unit_vector(axis)
    angle = -get_angle_between_vectors(point, direction)
    q = np.array([np.cos((angle/2)),*(norm_axis*np.sin(angle/2))])
    point_as_q = np.array([0,*point])
    q3 = quaternion_multiply(q, point_as_q)
    q3 = quaternion_multiply(q3, quaternion_conjugate(q))
    new_point = q3[1:]
    return new_point
```